# Method for converting strings into foreign key for a one-to-many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have a rails model `Region` for regions that I have visited.  `Region` has a one-to-many association with a `Location` model, which contains specific locations I have visited within that region.

Each region has a `name` string column.  My routes are set up such that a given `Region.name` is used to form most URLs -  `/:name/new_location` for example. This was for aesthetic reasons, as I did not want a number (the `region_id`) to form the URL.

Hence with every new location that I add to a region, a `region_id` foreign_key needs to be assigned.  Right now I am doing this by having a `region_name` column in my `Location`.  Then, my `new` location form has a field "Region name" where a string is entered.

To actually associate the newly created `location` with its `region`, the `create` method in my `locations_controller` contains a section of code as follows:

```
# CONVERT REGION_NAME TO REGION_ID

location = Location.new
l = location.region_name.downcase
if l == "chicagoland"
  location.region_id = 3
elsif l == "roadtrip 2016"
  location.region_id = 4
#...
end

location.save
redirect_to("/regions/#{region.name}/#{location.id}")
```

Hence with every new `region` I create, I cannot add new locations until I manually connect its string name with its `id` - by adding new code to the `create` method in my `locations_controller`.  So, if I create a new region called "Algonquin Provincial Park" with `id = 28`, I need to update my `locations_controller` - connecting `"algonquin provincial park"` to `28`, and setting the `location.region_id` to `28` .  This is obviously not optimal.

Is there a way to program my `new` and `create` methods such that a new `location` is automatically assigned a foreign_key equivalent to the `region_id` of the `region` it falls under, without having to add code to my `Location create` method every time there is a new `region`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a bit of intro, what you're trying to do is sometimes referred to a [pretty urls](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+pretty+urls) or [friendly urls](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+friendly+urls). You can roll your own, or use a gem. It looks like you've gone down the roll your own path (which is what I do, too). If your `name` field ever contains non-url friend elements, then you'll probably want to look into using `slugs`. I'll leave that for your own research.

In your `routes.rb`, let's assume you have:

```
resources :regions, param: :name do 
  resources :locations
end
```

Which will give you:

```
    region_locations GET    /regions/:region_name/locations(.:format)                locations#index
                     POST   /regions/:region_name/locations(.:format)                locations#create
 new_region_location GET    /regions/:region_name/locations/new(.:format)            locations#new
edit_region_location GET    /regions/:region_name/locations/:id/edit(.:format)       locations#edit
     region_location GET    /regions/:region_name/locations/:id(.:format)            locations#show
                     PATCH  /regions/:region_name/locations/:id(.:format)            locations#update
                     PUT    /regions/:region_name/locations/:id(.:format)            locations#update
                     DELETE /regions/:region_name/locations/:id(.:format)            locations#destroy
             regions GET    /regions(.:format)                                       regions#index
                     POST   /regions(.:format)                                       regions#create
          new_region GET    /regions/new(.:format)                                   regions#new
         edit_region GET    /regions/:name/edit(.:format)                            regions#edit
              region GET    /regions/:name(.:format)                                 regions#show
                     PATCH  /regions/:name(.:format)                                 regions#update
                     PUT    /regions/:name(.:format)                                 regions#update
                     DELETE /regions/:name(.:format)                                 regions#destroy
```

Let's also assume that you have:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end
```

And:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end
```

Then, in `locations_controller.rb`, do something like:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController 

  ...

  def create
    @region = Region.find_by(name: params[:region_name])
    @location = @region.locations.new(location_params)
    if @location.save
      redirect_to region_location_path(@region.name, @location)
    else
      # do something when the location doesn't save
    end
  end

  ...

private

  def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:some, :location, :attributes)
  end

end
```